# Can an application be used to behave like a function?

Tags: vb.net, interprocess, inter-process-communicat

I'm a beginner so I'll try to be as clear as I can.I want to know if it is possible to run a custom application and have it return and store a result in a boolean,int or string in another application(the one that calls it) ? Basically I want it to behave like a function that returns a value but to another program that calls it instead. I would like to do it in VB.net. Something like this when it comes to using boolean :

```
 a = Process.Start("C:\path_to\myapp.exe")
 if (a) then 
    'execute
 end if
```

Comment: If the executable writes anything to standard output then the code executing it could read that output and parse it for the information you need.  (Though it would be more involved than what you propose here.)  But it would be a *lot* easier if the code you're looking to invoke is in a class library that your code can reference, instead of trying to scrape the output from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

At the simplest level, no, the design of the process mechanism doesn't inherently afford the ability to do what you're suggesting. The closest you could get is for the called process to exit with a particular return value, but that requires use of a particular API (GetExitCodeProcess) - not the return from the Start method you've illustrated here.

You can do such things as capture the output of the new process, which isn't a very robust solution, or create a temporary file that contains a value the "calling" process can read, which is even less robust. The other extreme would be to investigate specific techniques for interprocess communication.

If you could expand a bit on your problem, a more specific set of possible solutions could be offered. If your value of interest is being generated by a library or some shared code, that might afford a much more suitable return mechanism.

Comment: Okay, What I'm trying to do is make a fingerprint matching app.Once it gets the right match I want it to send this as an input to another app. Problem is that I only have the rights to change certain things in the latter app via code. I don't have access to any of its protected methods or inbuilt classes etc. Pretty much all I can do is create new subs ( I haven't experimented with classes). My plan is that once a user presses a button in the app it will start the fingerprint app to check the fingerprint so when it finds a match it will inform the first app that the user can proceed.

Comment: What you're describing there involves some fairly complicated interprocess communication - eg process 1 sends data to process 2, waits, process 2 does something, then tells process 1 to continue, eg. That's very much the behavior you could see in an *individual* application, but choreographing that behavior among separate processes - one of which is closed in terms of code access or changes - is going to be very difficult. Not impossible, just difficult. It really sounds like you need a shared library of authentication for different apps to leverage...

Comment: Hmmm Okay thank you. Can you please point me in the right direction ? I tried searching online but couldn't find what I wanted. At the beginning I had considered what you said earlier about creating a temp file for the fingerprint app to write to and the 2nd app to read from but like you said its not robust plus I won't learn anything new since that's easy.

Comment: Well, if it were me and I had the task you've generally sketched out, I would look long and hard for any kind of library or published API from the fingerprint system that you could leverage from the app you are writing - the idea being to eliminate the dependency on the app over which you have no or only minimal control. Use those libraries to perform the fingerprint validation/authentication. If nothing like that exists, you could look into IPC channels (which seems great overkill in this situation).

Comment: I found something related to IPC channels by googling "interprocess communication" why would it be an overkill ? Will it interrupt or slow down the process controlled by the app that calls the fingerprint app ?

Comment: Adding IPC to these apps is overkill because, at a basic level, you're really just wanting to communicate a relatively simple value (from what I can infer). However, getting IPC channels open and working on both sides and then getting the synchronization working is what represents the high workload level for the objective you've described.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of ConsoleApplication :

```
Imports System.IO

Module Main

    Sub Main()
        Dim Output As Boolean = File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\file.txt")
        Console.WriteLine(Output)
    End Sub

End Module
```

And how to read the output (stdout) of the **previous console application** (**this function returns a** `Boolean`) :

```
Public Function GetOutput(executable As String) As Boolean
    Using p As New Process With {.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With {
            .CreateNoWindow = True,
            .FileName = executable,
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            .UseShellExecute = False}}
        p.Start()

        Dim output As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        p.WaitForExit()
        Return CBool(output.Trim)
    End Using
End Function
```

You can now do what you wanted to do by using this :

```
a = GetOutput("C:\path_to\myapp.exe")
If a Then
    'execute
End If
```

See also (in C#) : [How to make a Main Method of a console based application to return a string type](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a99a8b0d-fb49-4caf-8107-fc04bd48d3f9/how-to-make-a-main-method-of-a-console-based-application-to-return-a-string-type?forum=csharplanguage).